# check if database row is empty

Tags: php, html, database, insert, statements

I have a database wich looks like this:

```
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
| bogie_id | train_id | axle_nr | bogie_nr |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |       1 |          |
|        2 |        1 |       2 |          |
|        3 |        1 |       3 |          |
|        4 |        1 |       4 |          |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
```

As you can see the `"bogie_nr"` rows are empty.
No i wana make an if statement, wich checks if the rows are empty or filled in.
What i currently have:

```
    <div id="bogiebox">
        <tr> 
            <?php    
                $x = 1;  
                foreach($show_axle as $bogiebox){ ?>
                <input type='hidden' name='bogie_id[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]' value='<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>'>
                <td>
                    <?php 
                        if($bogiebox['bogie_nr'] == ''){
                    ?>
                        <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" value="<?= $x ?>" name='bogie_nr[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]'></td>
                    <?php
                        }
                        else{ 
                    ?>
                        <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" checked disabled></td><?php } }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </div>
```

And then the if statement:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['y'])){
            $bogiefilledin = false;
                if(!empty($_POST['bogie_nr'])) {
                    echo "everything is full?";
                }
                else {
                    echo "Fill in some more fields";
                }
        }
    ?>
```

It is not done yet! but what it should do is:
We check a checkbox or 2. press the send button, and the database inserts the number 1 for the 2 selected bogies. Then the page refeshes and all the checkboxes should have a value of 2. And on the next insert they will insert the value 2. and so on and so on.

But, what i would like = if i filled in my database like this:

```
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
| bogie_id | train_id | axle_nr | bogie_nr |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |       1 |     1    |
|        2 |        1 |       2 |     1    |
|        3 |        1 |       3 |     2    |
|        4 |        1 |       4 |          |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
```

I would like to see the else statement (Fill in some more fields). because the 4th axle is not in a bogie yet.

Right now the if else statement shows me: when i select 1 and press submit it says: *"everything is full!"* . and when i select nothing it says: "*Fill in some more fields.*". However it does not insert anything yet, so it should always say: Fill in some more fields!.

How do i do this??

Comment: bogie_nr  is a column not a row

Comment: I have answered some of your past bogie/axle/train questions (by the time you complete that project, you should credit SO for all the help you are getting :P), but this one is difficult to understand: it is unclear in what `if` you are having issues, what needs to be sent, or even the basic logic of the process: What is `y` and is it important? Where/How are you inserting the data? You say that it is not inserting data for the 4th axle, but you don't show the code in charge or the logic of the insert.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `if(!empty($_POST['bogie_nr']))` to this `if($_POST['bogie_nr']!='')`

Comment: Then it always says: everything is full?